# Complexity class for Optimization problems over #P functions

Tags: complexity-classes, optimization, counting-complexity

Is there any complexity class which contains problems that can be expressed as an optimization over polynomially many #P functions ? i.e:

$$\tilde{f}(x) = \text{Max}_{f \in F}f(x)$$

where $f\in\# P$.

Moreover, if I can reduce a #P-Complete function to this, by means of a polynomial time Turing reduction, am I allowed to say formally that:

$$\tilde{f} \in \#P-\text{Complete}$$

OR

$$FP^{\tilde{f}} \in FP^{\#P} $$

The latter seems more plausible to me than the former, but could anyone please tell me if I could use the former claim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in $\mathrm{FP^{\#P}}$, since you can compute it in poly time using oracle calls to compute the $f$s.  If you can poly-time Turing reduce a $\mathrm{\#P}$-complete problem to it, then $\tilde{f}$ is $\mathrm{\#P}$-hard but you can't say it's $\mathrm{\#P}$-complete unless you can show that it's in $\mathrm{\#P}$. That seems unlikely, to me, as I can't see any way of building a nondeterministic Turing machine to have that many accepting paths.

Since $\tilde{f}\in\mathrm{FP^{\#P}}$ and $\mathrm{FP^{FP^{\#P}}}=\mathrm{FP^{\#P}}$ (just compose the reductions), $\mathrm{FP}^{\tilde{f}}\subseteq \mathrm{FP^{\#P}}$.  Note that $\mathrm{FP}^{\tilde{f}}$ is a complexity class (all problems that are poly-time Turing reducible to $\tilde{f}$), not a problem.

Comment: Since I mentioned that $F$ is the set of all $\#P$ functions and $\tilde{f}$ is one of them, can't we say that $\tilde{f} \in\#P-\text{Complete}$ ?

Comment: $\tilde{f}$ is the maximum of a set of \#P functions, and that isn't obviously in \#P. Why do you think it's in \#P?

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something. "$\tilde{f}$ is the maximum amongst the set of all $\# P$ functions", which means $\tilde{f}$ is in $\# P$ because the maximization is only over the set of $\# P$ functions. Right ?

Comment: The definition given was $\tilde{f}(x) = \max_{f\in F}f(x)$, for some set $F\subseteq \#P$. That doesn't imply that $\tilde{f}\in F$, since the max is performed separately for each value of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an optimization problem whose measure function is a #P function, thus it is in Opt#P (see https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0204010).

I realized that your problem is related to a problem which I am considering to. You can see [Which complexity class does this problem belong to?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/45784/which-complexity-class-does-this-problem-belong-to?noredirect=1#comment101859_45784)